# How do i find the minimal polynomial over the field k?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

I have a field $k$ and $x$ is a variable, where $y=\frac{x^3}{x+1}$ how do I find the minimal polynomial of x over $K(y)$

I'm quite confused, I'm trying to use the theorem on primitive elements, so far I have:

$x^3-(x+1)y=x^3-\frac{(x+1)y}{x+1}=0 $

where do I go from here, to show that x is a minimal polynomial over $k(y)$?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^3-yx+y\in K[y][x]$, a polynomial ring over the P.I.D. $K[y]$. *Eisenstein's criterion* shows this polynomial is irreducible, hence it is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: The user is asking for minimal polynomial over $K(y)$, it is the smallest field containing $K$ and $y$, Eisenstein's criteria cannot be applied since $y^2 | y$,  $\, y^2 \cdot y^{-1} = y$

Comment: You seem to forget that $x$ is integral over $K[y]$ and that, in this ring $y^2\nmid y$.

Comment: $K[y]$ is not exactly the polynomial ring, right? So one would have to justify these calculations, right? (Namely the use of Eisenstein and claiming that $y$ is prime.) I'm guessing that one could show that $y$ is transcendental over $K$ and so, $K[y]$ is indeed (isomorphic to) the polynomial ring with one indeterminate but I'm not sure if I'm missing something simpler.

Comment: Here, as $y$ is rational fraction of the indeterminate $x$,  it is isomorphic to the polynomial ring in one indeterminate, that we may denote $x$  to have no confusion with $x$.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. Also, to be sure, to conclude irreducibility over $K(y)$, are you using Gauss' Lemma?

Comment: No, Eisenstein's criterion, since $K[y]$ is a P.I.D. – y is an irreducible element  dividing all coefficients but the leading coefficient, and $y^2$ does not divide the constant term.

Comment: Right but we need the polynomial to be irreducible over the field $K(y)$, right? Eisenstein only gives irreducibility over the ring $K[y]$?

Comment: A polynomial irreducible over a P.I.D.  is also irreducible over its field of fractions. I can't  remember exactly a reference  at the.moment.    Maybe it's true more generally over a U.F.D., or over an integrally closed domain, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Another way: apply the Rational Root Test to conclude that if $\,x^3 - x y + y\,$ is reducible over $\,k(y)\,$ then it has a root $\in k[y]\,$ which is a factor of the prime $y,\,$ contra a simple degree argument.